# How to Invoke a flow from LWC Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

In aura programming model, we could set input variables and invoke the flow like below.
**flow.startFlow("Delete_Contact_From_Account", inputVariables)**;

How do we achieve something similar in an LWC Component?
please note Lightning web component can now be added in flow screens.

Answer (score 1):

> after investigation, I found that as of now the only way is to wrap it
>   inside an aura component and fire event from lwc cmp to an aura when
>   on the onchange handler the flow is called.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Flows can now be embedded in LWCs.

Check it out: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow/documentation

You also get the methods you were looking for:

`resumeFlow()`
`startFlow()`